# How do I communicate with Android using node.js? (Mysql)

Tags: android, mysql, node.js

I am trying to communicate with Android on node server basis now. The database is using mysql. I usually do data exchange through json parsing, but I do not know how to use it. If there is a good way, I would appreciate it if you recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we have to use **REST API method** for  communicating client side application to node server. So host your application (Node server) and make rest call by using the hosted url.

Example: our node server hosted on http://example_host.com

we have create a rest method for getting data from the server.

Method : **GET**,  url : **/user_data**

so make a call like  : http://example_host.com/user_data

it will make a response with data.

Answer (score 0):

For REST check out the excellent retrofit project from square

http://square.github.io/retrofit/